# Unable to set list of hosts using the discovery.seed_hosts static setting

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to define a list of seed host providers in `elasticsearch.yml` using [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/modules-discovery-hosts-providers.html), it shows some errors which I have shared below.

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9500
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
192.168.1.10:9300
192.168.1.11
seeds.mydomain.com
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" 2020-05-01 15:10:08,817 main ERROR No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
SettingsException[Failed to load settings from [elasticsearch.yml]]; nested: MarkedYAMLException[while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 69, column 1:
    192.168.1.10:9300
    ^
could not find expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 70, column 1:
    192.168.1.11
    ^

 at [Source: sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream@565f390; line: 68, column: 21]]; nested: ScannerException[while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 69, column 1:
    192.168.1.10:9300
    ^
could not find expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 70, column 1:
    192.168.1.11
    ^
];
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1097)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromPath(Settings.java:1070)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.createEnv(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:95)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 69, column 1:
    192.168.1.10:9300
    ^
could not find expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 70, column 1:
    192.168.1.11
    ^

 at [Source: sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream@565f390; line: 68, column: 21]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException.from(MarkedYAMLException.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:343)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.nextToken(JsonXContentParser.java:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.fromXContent(Settings.java:645)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.fromXContent(Settings.java:620)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.access$400(Settings.java:82)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1093)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 69, column 1:
    192.168.1.10:9300
    ^
could not find expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 70, column 1:
    192.168.1.11
    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.stalePossibleSimpleKeys(ScannerImpl.java:465)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.needMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:280)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:225)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingValue.produce(ParserImpl.java:585)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:157)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:167)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:340)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to remove the hashtag `#` sign in front of the setting name `discovery.seed_hosts`. The # is used for comments so the settings parser can not find the corresponding setting-key of the values and therefore fails.

Furthermore, you need to put dashes before the values since the setting expects an array of values.

```
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
192.168.1.10:9300
192.168.1.11
seeds.mydomain.com
```

must be changed to

```
discovery.seed_hosts:
  - 192.168.1.10:9300
  - 192.168.1.11
  - seeds.mydomain.com
```